# push avro message to kafka topic

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-node

I'm trying to use the **kafka-node-avro**

library to push data to existing topic.
I already added the schema to the SchemaRegistry with curl and the topic also.
I get the following error:

```
Error: Topic name or id is needed to build Schema
    at new Shema (/work/node_modules/kafka-node-avro/lib/schema.js:7:41)
    at Object.Pool.getByName (/work/node_modules/kafka-node-avro/lib/schemaPool.js:70:10)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

My code snippet is the following:

```
const Settings = {
    "kafka" : {
        "kafkaHost" : config.KafkaHost
    },
    "schema": {
        "registry" : config.KafkaRegistry
    }
};

console.log("settings registry: ", config.KafkaRegistry);
console.log("settings kafkaHost: ", config.KafkaHost)
KafkaAvro.init(Settings).then( kafka => {
const producer = kafka.addProducer();
let payloads = [
    {
        topic: 'classifier-response-test',
        messages: JSON.stringify(kafkaData)
    }
];
producer.send(payloads).then( success => {
// Message was sent encoded with Avro Schema
    console.log("message sent ! Awesome ! :) ")
}, error => {
        // Something wrong happen
        console.log("There seems that there is a mistake ! try Again ;) ")
        console.log(error)
    });
} , error => {
    // something wrong happen
    console.log("There seems that there is a global mistake ! try Again ;) ")
    console.log(error)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The library is not ready to `send` a list of messages, reason why it complains when trying to add a Schema into the Schema Pool dynamically in the send mechanism. The easiest solution is to send 1 message at a time, in your code sample it could be like

```
const Settings = {
  "kafka" : {
    "kafkaHost" : config.KafkaHost
  },
  "schema": {
    "registry" : config.KafkaRegistry
  }
};

KafkaAvro.init(Settings).then( kafka => {
  kafka.send({
    topic: 'classifier-response-test',
    messages: JSON.stringify(kafkaData)
  }).then( success => {
    // Message was sent encoded with Avro Schema
    console.log("message sent ! Awesome ! :) ")
  }, error => {
    // Something wrong happen
    console.log("There seems that there is a mistake ! try Again ;) ")
    console.log(error)
  });
} , error => {
  // something wrong happen
  console.log("There seems that there is a global mistake ! try Again ;) ")
  console.log(error)
});
```

Thanks for using **kafka-node-avro**

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that we nedd to put the list of topics inside the schema settings to put the link between topic and schema registry.
we can put the schema id or the topic name.

```
const kafkaSettings  = {
    "kafka" : {
      "kafkaHost" : config.KafkaHost
    },
    "schema": {
      "registry" : config.KafkaRegistry,
      "topics": [
        {"name": "classifier-response-test" }
    ]
    }
  };
```

Comment: if u add topics like that u will get a connection error.